# Regular regex to Vimscript regex

Tags: regex, vim

I am a bit confused on the use of regular expressions in vimscript. I really tried but the `match` function does not return what I am expecting it to.. In the particular case I am trying to create a custom fold expression as such:

```
function! SuperColliderFolds()
  let thisline = getline(v:lnum)
  if match(thisline, '^[\s\t\n]*[[:lower:]]\w*\s*{') >= 0
    return "1"
  elseif match(thisline, '^entity'') >= 0
    return ">2"
  else
    return "="
  endif
endfunction
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=SuperColliderFolds()
```

The regular expression should fold all the methods of a class that has a structure like:

```
ClassName{
  methodName{//implementation
  }
}
```

but it does not work... It would be ideal to have help on the particular example but the question is more on "what am I missing regarding vimscript regular expressions?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the bottom line is that Vim has its own regex syntax that is really well documented. But I spend a lot of time trying to write the expression using `\v` at the start which it is said to turn the syntax into a more common one:

> If you simply start all of your regular expressions with \v you'll
>   never need to worry about Vimscript's three other crazy regex modes. ([Click here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/31.html) to view the full article.)

But this turned out to be really difficult as the verymagic mode (that is what the `\v` mode is called) does not seem to be as well documented as the default magic mode. So in the end I just used the manual to learn enough about the vim regex syntax and solved my problem using it.

For future reference here is my result (a custom fold expression for SuperCollider language classes):

```
  function! SuperColliderFolds()
  let thisline = getline(v:lnum)
  let previousline = v:lnum-1
  " match instance methods
  if match(thisline, '^\s\{1,5}\l\a*\s*{') >= 0
    return ">1"
  " match class methods
  elseif match(thisline, '^\s\{1,8}\*\l\a*\s*{') >= 0
    return ">1"
  " don't fold Class names
  elseif match (thisline, '^\s\{,3}\u\a*\s*{\|(:\s*{)') >= 0
    return "0"
  "match method closing brackets (assuming no more than 3 spaces intend which should be ok for my purpose)
  elseif match (getline(previousline), '^\s\{,3}}') >= 0
    return "0"
  else
    return "="
  endif
  endfunction
  setlocal foldmethod=expr
  setlocal foldexpr=SuperColliderFolds()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using POSIX character classes like `[[:lower:]]` is not working in the regex? What about using something like `[a-z]` - or even better `\l` - instead of `[[:lower:]]`?

Reference: http://vimregex.com/#pattern

Comment: Didn't do it but thanks for the reference! I am gonna study it.